# Is there a way to tell if an entity is attached while debugging / inspecting an entity in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to tell if an Entity Framework entity is attached to a context when debugging in visual studio 2013

I.e if i quick-watch an entity how would i know if its attached?

or would i need to write an extension method and quick-watch that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entity state by its entry:

```
context.Entry(entity).State
```

where `context` is your `DbContext` instance and `entity` is the entity to inspect.